# Differential of scalar function is a 1-Form. What for differential of vector-valued functions?

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ a continuously differentiable function. The the total differential $df$ is a differential $1$-form, i.e. $df(p)$ is a cotangent vector $df(p)\colon T_p(U)\to\mathbb{R}$, where $T_p(U)$ is the tangent space at $p\in U$.

Now, is there an analoug statement for the differential of a function $f\colon U\to\mathbb{R}^n$ with $U\subset\mathbb{R}^m$?

In this situation, the differential in $p$ is a map $df(p)\colon T_p(U)\to R^n$, isnt it?
Is it also a differential $k$-form?

Comment: Just think of a vector-valued function in terms of its component functions. If $f(x) = (f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x))$, then for any $v\in T_p(U)$, $df(p)(v) = (df_1(p)(v),\dots,df_n(p)(v))\in\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your last question th answer is not, that $dp$ is not a $k$-form. $k$-forms are obtained with the exterior derivative that is different form the total derivative on your post.

The coincidence here between the exterior derivative and the total derivative is because $T\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. But in general, you can compute the total derivative of a map between manifolds, while the exterior derivative only makes sense for $k$-forms. Namely, $k$-forms are antisymmetrizations of the tensor product of $1$-forms. You can get more information in Wiki for example, by searching *differential form*.

Suppose that $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a map between manifolds. Then, $df(p)$ maps to each tangent vector $X\in T_pM$ the vector field $Y\in T_{f(p)}N$ defined as the derivation $Y(g)=X(g\circ f)$.

Comment: For scalar function f, the total differential of f in p in U gives each tangent vector v in the tangent space at p it’s directional derivative in direction v. — Is this the same for vector-valued f?

Comment: Hmmm no. When the function is vector-valued (for example a map brwteen manifolds or into $\mathbb R^n$ as in your case) $df(p)$ is a linear transformation that sends tangent vectors at $p$ into tangent vectors of $f(p)$. And I'm not sure you can talk about directional derivatives in this case...

Comment: I don’t see why for vector valued function f we have that df(p) send tangent vectors at p to tangent vectors at f(p).

Comment: @Rhjg See the edit.